# Proper way to get excel sheet names using C# and oledb

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2015, oledb

I'm trying to figure out why the behavior I'm seeing and the "documented" behavior are different.  I've read both of these articles:[Read and Write Excel Documents Using OLEDB](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/705470/Read-and-Write-Excel-Documents-Using-OLEDB?msg=5257034#xx5257034xx) and [Working with MS Excel(xls / xlsx) Using MDAC and Oledb](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37055/Working-with-MS-Excel-xls-xlsx-Using-MDAC-and-Oled?msg=5257205#xx5257205xx) and this is text from the second link.

If you read in the second link it says:

> To Retrieve Schema Information of Excel Workbook :
>
> You can get the worksheets that are present in the excel workbook using GetOleDbSchemaTable. Use the following snippet.
>
> DataTable dtSchema = null;
>   dtSchema = conObj.GetOleDbSchemaTable(
>   OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
>
> Here dtSchema will hold the list of all workbooks. Say we have two workbooks : wb1, wb2. The above code will return a list of wb1, wb1$,wb2,wb2$. We need to filter out $ elements.

However when I run this code I only get "wb1$ and wb2$".  I can easily remove the $ in code but I'm trying to make sure I'm not going to have code that breaks when I put it on a different computers/OS/environment and it behaves as is documented.  Can somebody tell my what or if something changed since these were written or if I'm missing some key piece.  Something to note this is being developed in VS2015, Windows 7 Pro, and Office 2010 installed.

```
        //Connection String
        //string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1';";   // Extra blank space cannot appear in Office 2007 and the last version. And we need to pay attention on semicolon.
        //string connstring = Provider = Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = " + path + "; Extended Properties = 'Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1'; ";  //This connection string is appropriate for Office 2007 and the older version. We can select the most suitable connection string according to Office version or our program.

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            //DataTable sheetNames = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });  //Get All Sheets Name
            DataTable sheetNames = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);  //Get All Sheets Name
            // Loop through all Sheets to get data
            foreach (DataRow dr in sheetNames.Rows)
            {
                string sheetName = dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                //if (!sheetName.EndsWith("$"))
                //    continue;                    
                Debug.Print(sheetName);
            }
            return sheetNames;
```

Thanks

dbl

Comment: Using the ACE.OLEDB or JET.OLEDB driver you need wrap sheet names with [] if they have a space in the sheet name and add a $ at the end in all cases. If you are iterating Tables through those aforementioned providers, you should get the name back in that format. See https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/. Was that your question?

Comment: @RyanWildry No.  My issue is with the number of returned values not the format of those values.  I have updated the initial question to see if I can clarify it.  Please let me know.

Comment: Are there supposed to be 2 or 4 sheets returned?

Comment: @RyanWildry That's really my question.  Every example I can find says that if there are 2 sheets you are going to get 4 results..  One with a $ appended and one without.  But when I run the code I only get 2 results WITH the $ appended.  And I can program for that but counter to all the examples.

Comment: Gotcha. In my experience only the values with the $ appended at the end are going to work with a sql statement. If that's what you are doing with it then you should be good. If you are using Excel automation, e.g. VBA, you want to use the sheet name without the $.